# Add debugging info to os161

Tags: gdb, os161

I'm trying to debug os161 and am having trouble due to a lack of debug information. None of my functions have line number information, so I'm capable of doing something like "b lock_acquire" but then when I do "s" it says "Single stepping until exit from function lock_acquire, 
which has no line number information." I also get a "No line number known error" when I try to do "l lock_acquire", get "No symbol lock in current context." when I'm at lock_acquire and type "p lock". Furthermore when I type ptype curthread it says "data variable, no debug info found" instead of something useful. I used the config directions from here http://www.cdf.utoronto.ca/~csc369h/fall/docs/configure.shtml. Is there some way to add more debug info when you compile os161?

Edit:
To start gdb I type

```
% cd ~/os161/root
% sys161 -w kernel
```

in one window and then type

```
% cd ~/os161/root
% cs161-gdb kernel
(gdb) target remote unix:.sockets/gdb
```

in a second window.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways you can debug the kernel one way is directly add debug message to the kernel. For example
 add DEBUG macro in the system. (lib.h)

```
...
DEBUG(DB_SYSCALL, "Entering into user mode\n");
...
```

Another way you could use GDB like you just said. Instead of using 's' you should use 'n' and 'bt' to check the steps. Without reading any errors I don't know how to provide more information. I hope this helps.